# System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Tags: c#, sql, database, ms-access, oledb

I'm supposed to be able to type a postcode in a textbox, so when the program runs, its supposed to put a street name with the matching postcode in another textbox.

However, I'm getting this error And I can't really solve it. The error appears on this line:

```
leesAdres = Adres.ExecuteReader();
```

The whole code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication12
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnZoek_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
            OleDbCommand Adres = new OleDbCommand("Select `street` from `postcode` where `postcode` LIKE txtPostcode.Text", con);
            OleDbDataReader readAdres;
            con.ConnectionString = "provider=Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0; data Source = C:\\Users\\name\\Documents\\school\\Adodotnet\\postcode.accdb";

            con.Open();
            readAdres = Adres.ExecuteReader();

            while (leesAdres.Read())
            {
                txtStreet.Text = leesAdres.GetValue(0).ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I suspect it might be my SQL command but I'm not sure, I have no experience with SQL and databases.

Comment: I can confirm your suspicion on the SQL command: Instead of passing the value from your TextBox `txtPostcode` you actually submit the literal control name (and property).

Comment: @Filburt can you show me how to solve it? As I said, I'm new to this.

Comment: For future reference including the error message you see can help diagnose the issue

Comment: @BadAtPHP See DB010s answer to solve this issue but note that, as Liath points out, is considered bad practice. Look into passing query conditions as parameters. Otherwise your vulnerable to [Exploits Of A Mom](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are misconstructing your querystring in the line

```
"Select `street` from `postcode` where `postcode` LIKE txtPostcode.Text", con
```

It should be

```
"Select `street` from `postcode` where `postcode` LIKE '%" + txtPostcode.Text+ "%'" , con
```

To make your code more robust and to prevent SQL Injection, you would construct it of the form

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select `street` from `postcode` where `postcode` LIKE @P1" , conn);
cmd.Parameters.Add(P1);
cmd.Parameters["P1"].Value = txtTagNumber.Text;
```

Also look into the use of the stringbuilder class to construct the actual string.

Comment: While you're right I don't believe we should be advocating this sort of SQL. I'd suggest updating your answer so it's not vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. As it stands it's taking all my self control not do downvote...

Comment: Don't downvote. There could be a special check for content of `txtPostcode` (during validation). Simple warning about code injection is enough.

Comment: @Sinatr I was thinking more along the lines of paramaterised queries

Comment: @Liath he doesn't need to do that (for me) tough, this is just me practicing.

Also DB101 it worked! Thanks!

Comment: @BadAtPHP -- I wouldn't downvote, but Liath has the right of it.  If you're practicing, you need to get in to the good habits.   It is considered best practice to not use inline variables inside ad-hoc SQL.   Use string-builder and parameterized queries -- it protects from people attacking your SQL command.    Imagine if they put in a bunch of SQL inside your textbox and the code processed it like normal SQL.    Easy to trash your database - or lock it up forever with a WAIT command.

Comment: @BadAtPHP, I appreciate this is just a learning app. I was trying to make you aware of the weakness of this approach. It is VERY dangerous - I can't over stress it. Read up on parameterised queries for your next app

Comment: Use the following form to avoid SQL Injection[code]
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select `street` from `postcode` where `postcode` LIKE @P1" , conn);
cmd.Parameters.Add(P1);
[code]
cmd.Parameters["P1"].Value = txtTagNumber.Text;

Comment: @Jason I know it could be very dangerous and should be prevented, but I'm still learning the very basics. I'd rather take one step at a time then add all sort of things in it.

He may still post an example for other people tough. The more people who are are aware of it, the better.